# PyQt5 on gnome has strange file dialogs

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm trying to switch from qt4 to qt5, but one of the issues I'm seeing is that the open/save file dialogs have gotten really ugly! Files and folders no longer have icons, the shortcuts in the sidebar are displayed incorrectly etc.

Does anybody know why this is and how I can restore it?

Thanks,
  Michael

**Update:**

I don't specify which dialogs to use, so I guess I get whatever the default is. This is an open file dialog in PyQt4:

[image: An open file dialog in PyQt4]

And PyQt5:

[image]

The system is Fedora 24, with Gnome 3.20.2

Comment: Which file-dialog are you using: native, or qt's built-in one? It would be helpful if you added some screenshots to your question (i.e. one for qt4 and one for qt5).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, have updated my post! I don't specify which type to return, so in both cases I get whatever's the default. Perhaps this has changed between versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Qt4 one looks like the standard GTK+ file dialog while the second one looks like the built-in Qt fallback.

One possible reason for the latter happenning with identical code on your side is that your Qt5 installation is missing the GTK+ platform theme plugin or that this plugin cannot be loaded for some reason.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out there's a package called "QGnomePlatform" that's meant to provide tighter integration of qt apps into gnome, but that you need to _remove_ to get native file dialogs back...

Comment: On Xubuntu 16.04, I had to install the package `libqt5libqgtk2`